# SQL Server : convert string to Int when importing from CSV

Tags: sql-server, string, csv, import, int

In my CSV file, there is `AuthorID` by they are in string format

Is it possible in a SQL Server query, when importing a CSV, to convert `String` to `Integer`?

```
BULK
INSERT Author
FROM 'C:\author.csv'
WITH
(
FIRSTROW = 2,
<Convert Column 1 to Integer>
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

Comment: It should just work if you have a column of `int` type and all the values in csv are really numbers.

Comment: Agreed. This is the whole point of CSV-import. The CSV is type-agnostic, so it has to infer this from the destination column type. Are you getting any errors? In which case, you should post them in the question as well.

Comment: This is the error: Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 1 (pubId).

Answer (score 0):

for data manipulation whistle data transfer use SSIS packages, I dont think you can do anything with the data itself with bulk insert statement whistle you are inserting it into a table. The destination column should have the appropriate and the right DATATYPE and it should work.

 In you case if you set datatype for your destination column to be INT and you do not have any strings in your data it should work just fine. 
 If you still get errors then you should check you data that you are inserting and if there is any data that needs changing before it can be inserted in an INT datatype column then you might have to consider making use of SSIS package.